# Can't enter into boot menu of Asus Vivobook

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, password-recovery

I have an Asus Vivobook laptop running on Windows 8.1. But, I have forgotten the password to login to the system. Now I am trying to install Windows 10 via a bootable USB stick. But the problem is that I can't get into the boot menu no matter what I try.

I have tried all sorts of key combinations that I found online - **Esc, Del, F2, F10...** but none works.
This link: https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1008329/ shows how to get into the boot menu when logged into the system. But since I have forgotten the password, I can't get in. I tried restarting by long-pressing the Shift key and I get all other Advanced Startup options except *UEFI firmware settings*.

I never had experienced this type of issue in other laptops. Can anyone guide me through till the boot menu?

Answer (score 1):

As of today, I have finally been able to get into the boot menu. Since the *Fast startup* option was turned on, I was unable to hit the *Esc*  button at the correct time. As I tried some more times, I was in boot menu soon.

So, yeah... timing matters.